# Frightened but not surprised

Tags: motto

For purposes of a motto, what is the grammatically correct way of saying "Frightened but not surprised" in Latin? Best effort so far is "Petrificata sed non sorpresa". What are your thoughts?

Background: Would like to refine a humerous expression for people who have worked on many surprisingly stressful situations, initially expecting things should have been much easier than they turned out to be but now prepared for the worst and therefore, jokingly, scared. The reason i used petrified in my first attempt is because its a bit of a joke so ok to exaggerate.

Comment: The question should explain the meaning of the expression. E.g. were you expecting to be frightened? Or were you expecting something to happen but when it did it frightening you? Or what?

Comment: Thanks Ray, i added some extra detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, your attempt suffers from two problems:

- *Petrificatus, -a, -um* simply means “turned to stone.” It is not usually used figuratively, as in English.
- *Sorpresa* is perfectly correct and does mean “surprised,” just not in Latin (it's Italian).

From your explanation, I take it that you want to describe a woman/girl that is expecting terrible things, and therefore fearful of what will come, but who is not oblivious to the danger and will not be surprised when things turn out difficult.

I would therefore suggest: **metuens sed non inopinans** – literally: “afraid (apprehensive), but not unsuspecting.” *Metus* is the fear of impending evil, a justified apprehension. *Inopinans* is often used in a military context, when an enemy is caught unprepared. This expression happens to be gender-neutral, so it works for males as well.

By the way, I believe you can also make this even a little crisper by saying: *metuens **nec** inopinans*. *Nec* (= *neque*) really means “and not,” but where the joined elements do not really complement each other, it is often translated as “but not.”

Comment: Sorpresa is Spanish for surprise

Answer (score 0):

Students sometimes confuse present participles (verbal adjectives which describe what a noun is doing) with gerunds (verbal nouns which are things with an active quality). Examples of the former are in Sebastian's answer; the latter, the Jack-Nicholson film, "The Shining" (1980)--the shining was a psychic power--a noun with a verbal quality.

Here, the nominatives of the gerunds (the infinitives): "metuere sed non deprehendere" = "(the) fearing but not (the) surprising".

EDIT 19/9/2023:

Thanks to Brian and Sebastian. This was far trickier than I'd anticipated! The original answer was, "metuere sine deprehendendo" = "(the) fearing without (the) surprising". This, not necessarily incorrect, as just obscure and might have sounded odd to Roman ears. These things are worth knowing.

The use of "deprehendo" = "surprise" is attested: "cum sine duce et sine equitatu deprehensis hostibus..." = "when having surprised the enemy without either general or cavalry..." (Caes. de Bel. Gal. 7.52.2).

Comment: I have never seen a gerund used with *sine*, and a quick search seems to confirm my intuition. Here is [Allen & Greenough &sect; 307](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/gerund-and-gerundive): "The ablative of the gerund and gerundive is used (1) to express manner, means, cause, etc.; (2) after comparatives; and (3) after the propositions ab, dē, ex, in, and (rarely) prō."

Comment: @brianpck: Thank you. Is it certain then that "sine" is disqualified, in this context? I'll change the answer.

Comment: Just realized that I asked a [somewhat similar question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/approaches-to-translating-without-verb) a while back. @cnread pointed out that another grammar points to only two extant places where sine+gerund is used: so I suppose it isn't impossible, but I think other constructions are far more common.

Comment: Surely it would have to be *... sed non deprehendi*? (But I think this word would more readily be understood as "being caught").

Comment: @Sebastian Koppehel: In the OP's request "the fearing" and "the surprising" seemed to be concomitant. When I read your answer I began looking for verbs "to surprise"; just like verbs, "to forget", there aren't many!

Comment: @tony I agree it's a problem. That's also why my translation isn't very literal and doesn't actually say "surprised."

Comment: @Sebastian Koppehel: Of course. I wondered why you hadn't used "surprised", until I tried to find a Latin equivalent.